# ROS-I training_unit demo_manipulation fails to build

Tags: ros, catkin, tutorials, ros-industrial, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

This [exercise](http://aeswiki.datasys.swri.edu/rositraining/indigo/Exercises/demo/part2) is failing to build on my system due to the following error:

```
/home/work/ros_industrial_training/training/work/demo_manipulation/src/robot_io/src/nodes/simulated_grasp_action_server.cpp:35:70: fatal error: object_manipulation_msgs/GraspHandPostureExecutionAction.h: No such file or directory #include <object_manipulation_msgs/GraspHandPostureExecutionAction.h>
```

I was going to build the [object_manipulation_msgs](https://github.com/ros-interactive-manipulation/object_manipulation.git) from sources but it is a rosbuild project not catkin. Is there a way to easily convert this to catkin? There is a branch on the github with a couple of folders 'catkinized' but I don't think it's enough as catkin doesn't seem to detect anything.

Thanks for your help.

{UPDATE #1]

Adding the dependency didn't work but copying the `object_manipulation_msgs` src folder from the supplements directory did the trick. Not sure if that is how it is supposed to be done or if catkin should be automatically detecting the folder in the supplements directory.

[UPDATE #2]

There are a host of other errors as well when launching the roslaunch file after building:

1. The files `ur5.transmission.xacro` and `ur5.gazebo.xacro` are missing from the `ur_description` folder and need to be copied over from the supplements folder.
2. The `ur5.urdf.xacro` file has errors in the `<mesh>` and `<collision>` filename tags that also need to be corrected.

[UPDATE #3]

Opened 2 separate [issues](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_training/issues)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227737/ros-i-training_unit-demo_manipulation-fails-to-build/) by [atoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/26090/atoz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2016-02-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-28**:
Looking at your last two edits, I'm getting the feeling that something is not working correctly wrt how you overlay on the supplements directories. The errors you mention are a result of the *non-supplement* pkgs having been updated outside of the tutorials. The same for `object_manipulation_msgs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest to report this to the `industrial_training` [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_training/issues). There might be some `add_dependencies(..)` missing for the `simulated_grasp_action_server`, causing you to run into this error.

> I was going to build the [object_manipulation_msgs](https://github.com/ros-interactive-manipulation/object_manipulation.git) from sources but it is a rosbuild project not catkin. Is there a way to easily convert this to catkin? There is a branch on the github with a couple of folders 'catkinized' but I don't think it's enough as catkin doesn't seem to detect anything.

The `object_manipulation_msgs` version that is in the `industrial_training` repository is actually a Catkin package. See [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_training/tree/4a5fe58a72a3cb0a130ef31f778026e9d7713847/training/supplements/src/object_manipulation_msgs).

Could you try to add a `add_dependencies(simulated_grasp_action_server ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})` to the `CMakLists.txt` [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_training/blob/d372821fc486c8697e9feb42b12773da2c4e27d6/training/orig/demo_manipulation/src/robot_io/CMakeLists.txt#L61-L62)?

---

Edit:

> Adding the dependency didn't work but copying the `object_manipulation_msgs` src folder from the supplements directory did the trick. Not sure if that is how it is supposed to be done or if catkin should be automatically detecting the folder in the supplements directory.

No, that is definitely not how that is supposed to work. This is at best a work-around.

> I can't select your comment as the answer, should I just close this question? Thanks for your help

Please keep this open until we've actually fixed it.

I can't find your issue at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_training/issues). Have you reported it? That would give the maintainers a chance to fix this at the source.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2